# Tag synonyms should not be allowed for moderator-only and required tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, moderator-tags, required-tags

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed&sort=info&pagesize=50

I was curious what would happen if I proposed a synonym for a moderator-only tag... and it went through. This is a pretty big hole in the system if the proposed synonym gets accepted and actual retags end up putting a moderator-only tag on questions.

Proposing synonyms for mod-only tags should be *strictly* disallowed, and while I didn't try, I'm assuming required tags exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: checked in a fix in dev

Comment: @waffles: Thanks! I noticed you nuked the proposed synonym. Once this is deployed, I'll have to find another way to break the system. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why they shouldn't be allowed for required tags -- shouldn't it just be that the direction is forced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the theory is that this is fixed now, you should get an error telling you that its not allowed.